# display mat file in matlab

Tags: file, matlab

I want to display mat file's content to see all the results. I know that I can load it and then double click on it the content are display in the workspace, this case happen when the mat file content few information  but when I have mat file content information for more than 13000 record I can't display it. could please any one help me to find any way to display mat file as table?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if field exists in Matlab struct without loading it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026690/check-if-field-exists-in-matlab-struct-without-loading-it)

Comment: disagree with gnovice's comment: the link is just about checking if a field exists in a MAT file, this seems to be about loading a subset of the MAT file so it can be manipulated

Answer (score 5):

I do not know the format of your data (multi-dimensional, structs, cell-arrays), but there is a function called "openvar" which can be very useful for these things.

Let's define a large random 500x500x10 3d-matrix:

```
large = rand(500,500,10);
```

This variable contains 2.5 million double-values and takes up close to 20MB of memory. Opening this in the variable editor by double click in the Workspace window on "large" will usually (atleast on my system) give the following message:

```
"Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements."
```

But you can use the "openvar"-function to open certain parts:

```
openvar('large(:,:,1)'); %# pass the argument as a string.
```

This will open the first "layer" of matrices in your Variable Editor (a 500x500 matrix in this case). This is useful if you need to look into certain parts of a large variable.

Of course you can always define new variables that contain subsets of your larger variable:

```
less_large = large(:,:,1);
```

... and then open "less_large" in the variable editor by double clicking on it in the workspace-window. But sometimes the "openvar"-method is a bit faster/easier.

Comment: thanks for replying, the format of my data is struct of array contain image file name and another variables contains numeric values like color histogram

Comment: @zenab: I am not sure I understand completely. How large is the file in megabytes? Can you open the entire file into the workspace? Because if not, then my methods above will have little value to you.

Comment: I wil give you the following example for using openvar function : my mat file(colHist.mat) this file contain the struct of array (col) this struct of array contain the following fields: Nam(image name), ColHis(color histogram),first I load the (colHist.mat), then i write :  openvar(col.Nam), but I get empty worksheet in the matlab work space, please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.  Starting from a clear workspace, you could load the mat file into the workspace.  Anything now in the workspace is in the mat file.  You can use the variable viewer or parse with scripts.

If you have the Simulink toolbox, you can use Simulink.saveVars to save the contents of the workspace to a human readable m-script that would generate the same contents. It's a shame that you need Simulink to do this, as this function has nothing to do with Simulink.

Answer (score 1):

How about after loading the data, and use `whos` to display the variables in current workspace? Note that you may want to clear all the other variables before displaying them.